# Is it possible to populate PDF output from binary code on CPQ via custom action?

Tags: .net, ironpython, sap-erp

Is it possible to populate PDF output from binary code on CPQ via custom action? I would like to populate PDF output from binary code that comes from ERP system. SAP CPQ uses Ironpython for scripts and I am just a beginner on Ironpython. If it's possible can anyone share an example?

Thank you best regards.

Comment: Look at `reportlab` for creating PDFs in Python.

Comment: We cannot import all the libraries which you usually import via Python. In CPQ we use IronPython and not exactly Python. We import .NET Namespaces as CPQ built on C#.  Any .NET recommendations?

Comment: No. But I think even an IronPython program can use `reportlab` if programmers are prepared to convert their `IronPython` .NET strings into Python strings before doing calls. Or simply write a conversion layer. The easy bits would very likely be boring and the difficult bits would be fun.